# how to check whether a key/value is present in namevaluecollection with linq

Tags: asp.net

how to check whether a key/value is present in NameValueCollection with LINQ
I have a Name-Value collection with some key and its corresponding values. I need to check whether a particular key or value is present in the collection. I need the vb.net code for this

I need to use LINQ. Can u provide the LINQ statements to get the items from the NameValueCollection

I am filling the Name - Value collection with same keys having multiple values. I want to check whether a particular key with a particular value is there in the collection

this is the code

```
Dim nvproducts as new namevaluecollectionn
nvproducts.Add("1", "A")
nvproducts.Add("1", "I")
nvproducts.Add("2", "I")
nvproducts.Add("1", "A")
```

From this namevaluecollection i need to check whetehr a key with 1 and value A is there in the namevaluecollection. and i would like to do it in linq

Comment: show what you have done so far

Comment: I need to use LINQ.Can u provide the LINQ statements to get the items from the namevaluecollection

Answer (score 0):

you can use Count property of the NameValueCollection [NameVlaueCollectionCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.count.aspx)

```
 NameValueCollection myCol = new NameValueCollection();
      myCol.Add( "red", "rojo" );
      myCol.Add( "green", "verde" );
      myCol.Add( "blue", "azul" );
      myCol.Add( "red", "rouge" );
```

for Getting Total Count use like this

```
int TotalCount = myCol.Count;
```

to iterate over it use like this

```
 foreach ( String s in myCol.AllKeys )
         Console.WriteLine( " Key  {0,-10} Value: {1}", s, myCol[s] );
```

you can refer this link for more info [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx)

**updated** : try like this to get the count of the all values for the particular Key

`var ValuesCount= myCol.GetValues("red").Count()`

Comment: I need to use LINQ.Can u provide the LINQ statements to get the items from the namevaluecollection

Comment: why Linq ? u can achieve without linq na ?

Comment: i am filling the namevalue collection with same keys having multiple values.I want to check whether a particular key with a particular value is there in the collection

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have

```
NameValueCollection myCol = new NameValueCollection();
myCol.Add("key1", "value1");
myCol.Add("key2", "value2");
myCol.Add("key2", "value3");

string k = "key2";
string v = "value2";
```

then you can check if key `k` has value `v` like this:

```
bool result = 
        myCol.AllKeys.Contains(k) && 
        myCol.GetValues(k).Contains(v);
```

or something like this:

```
bool result =
      (from string key in myCol.AllKeys
       where key == k
       select myCol.GetValues(k).Contains(v)
      ).FirstOrDefault(hasValue => hasValue == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

more easy

```
    Dim lbHasKey As Boolean
    Try
        Dim lsValue As String = mShowCountInMemoryColl.Get(lsCodigoID)
        lbHasKey = True
    Catch exHasKey As Exception
        lbHasKey = False
    End Try
```